# Connect to different Datasource using JPA with spring datasource instance

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a use-case in which I have to communicate with two different Mysql databases.

Using MysqlTemplate I am successfully able to implement my use-case using below code

```
 @Configuration
    public class MySqlConfiguration {
        @Primary
        @Bean(name = "dbA")
        @ConfigurationProperties("spring.url-a")
        public DataSource dbA() {
            return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        @Qualifier("jdbcDbA")
        public JdbcTemplate dbATemplate(@Qualifier("dbA") DataSource dataSource) {
            return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        }

        @Bean(name = "dbB")
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.url-b")
        public DataSource dbB() {
            return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        }

        @Bean
        @Qualifier("jdbcdbB")
        public JdbcTemplate dbBTemplate(@Qualifier("dbB") DataSource dataSource) {
            return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        }
    }
```

This above code initializes two different instances of `JdbcTemplate` template (one each for a data source).

What I am trying to do now is:

If we want to connect to two different data sources(Mysql) using JPA,
according to spring-official [github code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/multiple-datasources), we can do it.

But can we use above two different `jdbcTemplate` for communicating with different MySQL databases using `JPA repository`?

What I believe is that internally `JPA` is also using an instance of the database(`jdbcTemplate`).

So is it possible to somehow pass an instance of the database to `JPA repository` and communicate with different databases?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, new answer now I have read the question correctly.  You will need 2 transaction managers, one for each data base.

Your Config above should be something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class JpaConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource1() {
        return DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .username("")
                .password("")
                .url("")
                .driverClassName("")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager1(DataSource dataSource1) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource1);
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("entities for dataSource 1");
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager1")
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager1(EntityManagerFactory entityManager1) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManager1);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource2() {
        return DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .username("")
                .password("")
                .url("")
                .driverClassName("")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager2(DataSource dataSource2) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource2);
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("entities for dataSource 2");
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager2")
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager2(EntityManagerFactory entityManager2) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManager2);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Then in your service, or DAO you can decide which database to use

```
@Service
@Transactional(transactionManager = "transactionManager1")
public class Service {
```

Comment: Can we use different databases at same time using this?