# how to create two data source in springboot where secondary database is dependent upon the primary database (Initially secondary database is unknown)

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to create an application with two db connection where secondary db connection is selected on the basis of primary.

I have created two datasource one as @primary and secondary i created after the home page loaded but wasn't working

Comment: this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772910/connect-to-different-datasource-using-jpa-with-spring-datasource-instance/46773266#46773266) may be helpful

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with "it wasn't working"? Did you get any errors? What code are you using?

Comment: i want to create an secondary datasource on the basis of requesturl (which i already stored in my primary db with a db name)

Comment: @EssexBoy thanks but my second db is dependent upon the first one (on the basis of url i am going to choose 2nd db)

Answer (score 0):

```
i have done something like this but not able to create second one
    package com.example.Configuration;    
    import com.example.model.User;
    import com.example.model.UserDaoImpl;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
    import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    
    import javax.sql.DataSource;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;
    import java.util.stream.Stream;
    
    
    @Component
    public class Registry {
        private static final Map<String, Object> registry = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    
        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("jdbcTemplate1")
        private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate1;
    
        public String getdb()
        {
    
                String sql1 = "select email from user1";
                List<User> list1 = jdbcTemplate1.query(sql1, new UserDaoImpl.UserRowMapper());
                return list1.get(0).getEmail();
        }
        @Bean(name = "db2")
        @DependsOn("db1")
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.second-db")
        public DataSource dataSource2() {
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            try {
    
    
    
                dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                String jdbcurl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+getdb();
                dataSource.setUrl(jdbcurl);
                dataSource.setUsername("root");
                dataSource.setPassword("hrhk");
                return dataSource;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return dataSource;
            }
        }
    
        @Bean(name = "jdbcTemplate2")
        @DependsOn("jdbcTemplate1")
        public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate2(@Qualifier("db2") DataSource ds) {
            if(ds==null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else {
                return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
            }
        }
    
    }
```